# Page not getting redirected when sessions are not set - PHP

Tags: php, session, redirect

In *home.php* page, if session is not set I want to redirect to index page. But it is not getting redirected. Session will be set only if I login to the project. However, currently I am not logged in, so sessions are not set.

```
require_once 'header.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['uid']) && !isset($_SESSION['uname']))
{    
   //echo "hai";                       // works
   header("location:index.php");
   exit;
} 
echo "hello";   // does not work
```

In *header.php* page I am starting session like

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Can anyone help me to find the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u enabled display errors? there might an error, also vardump($_SESSION) and check what it returns.

Answer (score 2):

The correct format to redirect is via `header` is :

```
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

Uppercase `L`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like that and tell me how it is working:

```
require_once 'includes/header.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['US_Id']) && !isset($_SESSION['US_UName']))
{    
   header("Location: /index.php");
   exit;
}
```

Be sure to remove all the symbols (even the empty spaces) before the opening tag `<?php` and after the closing tag `?>` in both your file and the header.php.

Having anything there will make impossible for the headers to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are formatting wrong and you cannot use a relative path

Change it to:

```
header("Location: http://yoursite.com/index.php");
```